# class cast exception on using xmlresouceparser with Document

Tags: android

Hi all i have a class cast exception, No idea what is this, Can any one help on this

```
XmlResourceParser fXmlFile = mn.getResources().getXml(R.layout.savecredentials);
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse((InputStream) fXmlFile); //exception is on //this line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're casting an XmlResourceParser

```
XmlResourceParser fXmlFile = mn.getResources().getXml(R.layout.savecredentials);
```

to an InputStream:

```
docBuilder.parse((InputStream) fXmlFile);
```

Comment: yes i have done that, if the class cast is coming for that, Then what should be the solution to remove class cast exception.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that you probably can't cast an InputStream to an XmlResourceParser, that's why you get the error.

Comment: I know that, But if you also know what the solution please help me.

Comment: You need to read the android API docs for that. Here is a basic example of using an xml parser, to get you started: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html